# Change selectedColor dynamically in jqvamp

Tags: javascript, html, dictionary, svg

I am using `jqvamp` plugin and I would like to change `selectedColor` property dynamically (by clicking on another button ) but I can't figure it out how.

Comment: I have no idea about `jqvamp`  but you can achieve it by using JS, Can i write sample code

Answer (score 1):

```
var your_variable = "";
// solution 1
// by click 
$('#your_button').click(function(){
your_variable= target_color;
// run the initialization again
test();
});

function test(){
set = $('#map').vectorMap({
//...code
selectedColor: your_variable
//...code
});
}

// solution 2
$('#your_button').click(function(){
$('#map').vectorMap("set", "selectedColor", your_variable);
});
```

hope this works